# window.onbeforeunload not working on Firefox 46 in a popup window, all other browsers work

Tags: firefox, onbeforeunload

Having an issue with Firefox 46, on all the other browsers it work fine.
Upon exit from the page I ask the following question. Firefox ignores it completely.
Help please!

```
window.onbeforeunload = ThisCheckExittingPage;

var ThisCheckExitWindow = 1;

// Checks before exitting
// ThisCheckExitWindow = 1;

// Does NOT check before exitting
// ThisCheckExitWindow = 0;

function ThisCheckExittingPage() {

    if (ThisCheckExitWindow == 1)
    {
        return "You are about to exit this page.";
    }
}
```

Comment: WFM on PaleMoon 26.2.1 (uses a recent fork of Gecko), so it's probably something new. If the page is a popup, it must be https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681636.

Comment: Yes, the script is running in a popup. I see, so its been an issue for quite a while in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like by design, as [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) has this note:

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created
>   in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted
>   with. Firefox has implemented this policy since Firefox 44 ([Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636905)).

As the [relevant patch](https://reviewboard.mozilla.org/r/20215/diff/3) shows, the `mUserHasInteracted` flag variable is set after a mouse or keyboard event happens in the window.

Comment: @Ben so, did you test if the handler fires after you interact with the window?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I take it back, yes it works on Firefox after interaction with the page. I had a function that was being called on page loading that was disabling my ThisCheckExittingPage() function. By the way Edge behaves like Firefox in this matter. Thanks for your help, everything works fine now.